# Is it true to say neurons like to be stimulated?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuron

I believe I have heard people saying "Neurons like to be stimulated". Although I know stimulating the brain promotes more neurons and connections growth, but does stimulating a neuron benefit the neuron itself? Or on the contrary, if a neuron is not stimulated long enough, does that cause any harm to itself? And then if that is true, can I say that limiting oneself to a narrow spectrum of stimuli is not good in general, considering there are other parts of the neural network not stimulated enough equally?

Comment: There's some anthropomorphism here, which might be unhelpful to your question, and then there is a huge generalization, which technically does not follow the first question. What's good for the goose here (the neuron) isn't necessarily good for the gander (the brain), as they are not equal.

Comment: I think it's necessary to clarify what someone *means* when they say this before evaluating whether it is *true* or not. Too many possible meanings to evaluate otherwise.